# Insert hyperlink in a cell and open a hidden sheet [Excel VBA]

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm new to excel VBA and I am trying to accomplish inserting a hyperlink in a cell using a VBA code. Upon clicking that value, I want to be able to open a hidden sheet.

What I have accomplished so far is this: open a hidden sheet using ***buttons***.

```
Sub mainModule(ByVal a_Sheets As String)

'Hide all tabs
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If sht.Name <> "MAIN" Then sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Next

'View tabs when button is clicked
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(a_Sheets, ","))
Sheets(Split(a_Sheets, ",")(i)).Visible = True
Sheets(Split(a_Sheets, ",")(i)).Activate
Next

End Sub

Sub goHere_Click()

Call mainModule("BIRTHDAYS")

End Sub
```

What I want to do is when I click "GO HERE", it will open the hidden sheet.

### [image]

Moreover, I found something that might help me solve this.

```
Sub sbCreatingHyperLink()
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A5"), "https://www.google.com"
End Sub
```

Could help me figure out a way wherein instead of "https://www.google.com", it will call a function module instead (`Call mainModule("BIRTHDAYS")`)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the hyperlinks dynamically into Sheet1 you would need to use something like the following:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet
i = 1
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:=ws.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Go To:"
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you would need to also change the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink to see if the hyperlink has been clicked and if so unhide the Sheet and show it. Something like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Sheet2.Select
    End If
    'copy the if statement above for each hyperlink
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

So in my testing I have 5 sheets all of them xlSheetVeryHidden apart from the first one that is called "Main", when I run the macro below the following hyperlinks are created:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet
i = 1
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Main" Then
        Sheets("Main").Cells(i, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheet1.Cells(i, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:=ws.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:="Go To:"
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The code above creates the following (ignoring the first sheet "Main"):

[image]

Then behind the first Sheet's code I entered this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$2" Then
        Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Sheet2.Select
    End If
    'copy the if statement above for each hyperlink
End Sub
```

This is where I placed the code:

[image]

The issue with this set up, is that even though the hyperlinks can be created dynamically by the macro foo(), to change the visibility you would have to manually add each Target.Range.Address to unhide the relevant sheet, so in my example I've only coded it so that if the user clicks on A2 of Sheet 1, which contains the hyperlink, then Sheet2 would become visible and you would navigate to it...

Comment: Hi, thank you for this but I tried it and it didn't work. I also updated the question.

Comment: I have tried and tested the above solution, it does work for me,... you are not able to call a function straight through the hyperlink click, but what you can do is add the hyperlink and have the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink do the unhiding for you before following to do the selection (got to the relevant sheet)... If you need a better walk-through as to how to implement the above solution, I can update my answer with some step by step guide?

Comment: Hi Xabier, I may need the step by step guide for this. Hoping for your understanding, I'm really new to this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff I've updated my answer and gave you step by step scenario of how I set it up, please have a look and give it a try, I'm sure you'll get it working... :)

Comment: Hi Xabier, I think I'm starting to understand the logic. I'm still trying this out. I will update you if I got it working or if I have further questions. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Xabier, it is now working. Thank you for the detailed explanation. This means a lot to me.